# Continuous maps between $i$-spheres and space $X$

Tags: algebraic-topology

This is probably something really simple but I don't seem to be able to see it, probably because of my lack of experience in algebraic topology. Anyway, we consider maps $\omega:(S^i,1) \rightarrow (X,x_0)$ and regard the $i$-sphere as the suspension of the $(i-1)$ sphere, $S^i=S(S^{i-1})$. We take the corresponding "polar coordinates" on $S^i$, so that $[r,x] \in S(S^{i-1})$, where $r \in I$ and $x \in S^{i-1}$, and we take $[0,1]$ as the base-point. So, for the case $i=1$, this map, if I understand things correctly, is supposed to give me the loops in $X$ based at $x_{0}$ ([more background in this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3433988/basepoint-homomorphism)). If we take $S(S^{0})$ we get that $(-1,1) \sim (1,1) $ and $(-1,0) \sim (1,0)$. What happens to the rest of the points in $S^0 \times I$?  And how do I get the loop in $X$ by applying $\omega$ to $[1,1]$ and $[1,0]$? Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi, it isn't clear to me what you are asking. Are you asking why the suspension of $S^0$ is $S^1$? Or are you asking something about $[S^n , X]$?

Comment: Hi @ConnorMalin. I am not sure how the maps $\omega$, for $i=1$, give me a loop in $X$  based at $x_0$. What even are these maps? If you look at the other question which I linked (apologies for cross-referencing) it should become clearer. On top of that, if we take the suspension of some space $X$ what happens to all the points that don't land in any of the equivalence classes?

Comment: If you define a loop to be a map $f:[0,1] \rightarrow X$ so $f(0)=f(1)$ this is the same as the map $f:[0,1]/\{0 \sim 1\} \rightarrow X$ and $[0,1]/\{0 \sim 1\} \cong S^1$.